# how can I update the newest react-native-reanimated version with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

how can I update the newest react-native-reanimated version with expo ?

if I write this:

```
npx expo install react-native-reanimated
```

then I dont get the latest reanimated version

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install react-native-reanimated` for the latest or change `package.json` yourself and run `npm install` afterwards. Remember that expo has ben tested against fixed versions of reanimated, so you will get warnings from expo if you upgrade it yourself.